# Proverb on hot weather

Tags: proverbs

Is there a proverb which can be used to tell someone that it's OK that the weather is so hot because it won't do them any harm (heat stroke and sunstroke are out of the question)?

For example, *Oh, it's so hot today! - It's OK! ...* (the proverb)

Answer (score 2):

"A little hot weather never killed anyone."

This is a common saying of the form *a little X never killed anyone* where X can be almost anything.

Be sure to use a gentle tone. If you laugh, you may sound rude to some English speakers.